# Multiple types from config file C#

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I am trying to pull in multiple sections from a configuration file. I thought that `GetConfigNode("MyObject");` would pull in all sections with that as the type. I am working on enhancing the current application, which previously all had distinct types. However I need to have the same type for the new section I need to add and it also needs to be a completely new section (with the ProcessName being different). Right now if I run this, only one section gets pulled into the list and I am not sure how to grab any sections with the same name into a list to then iterate over.

I have a config file that holds some mapping information:

```
<Uploads>
    <Upload ProcessName="ObjectName1" Type="MyObject">
          <FieldMapping SourceField="Name" DestinationField="Name1"/>
    </Upload>
    <Upload ProcessName="ObjectName2" Type="MyObject">
          <FieldMapping SourceField="Address" DestinationField="Address1"/>
    </Upload>
</Uploads>
```

Code behind:

```
private static bool Upload()
{
            List<UploadElement> UpEle = GetConfigNode("MyObject");
            // rest of code
}
```

EDIT--

```
    private static List<UploadElement> GetConfigNode(string node)
    {
        APIConfig Altx = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Uploads") as APIConfig;
        List<UploadElement> UpEle = new List<UploadElement>();
        foreach (UploadElement t in Altx.Elements)
        {
            if (t.UploadType.ToString().ToLower() == node.ToLower()) UpEle.Add(t);
        }

        if (UpEle == null) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("no " + node + " node found"); Environment.Exit(99); 
        }
        return UpEle;
    }
```

ApiConfig:

```
public class APIConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public UploadCollection Elements
    {
        get { return (UploadCollection)base[""]; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the implementation of GetConfigNode()

Comment: Sorry.. added that now @MichaelG

Comment: Do you have a common ancestor, like `UploadGroup`?

Comment: Also, what's `ApiConfig`?

Comment: They do.. they are all part of Uploads

Comment: Maybe this blog will help? http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/net-custom-configuration-section-collection-and-elements/

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Uploads")` seems to only pull in the furthest to the bottom section with the same name.. all others are ignored